# How to convert values of object with dynamic properties into array

Tags: javascript

I have object like this:

```
titles: {
   dr: 'Dr',
   prof: 'Prof',
   profdr: 'Prof Dr'
}
```

How can I transform it into array like this:

```
['Dr', 'Prof', 'Prof Dr']
```

Method should be dynamic because I need it for multiple objects with different number of properties.

Comment: You can use the `map` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const titles = {
   dr: 'Dr',
   prof: 'Prof',
   profdr: 'Prof Dr'
}
console.log(Object.values(titles));
```